# Find the measure of $\angle G$ in a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving, congruences-geometry

In the following figure, $\Delta$ADB, $\Delta$PCB and $\Delta$EFG are right triangles.
$PB=AE$,$AC=CB$.

**Question:**  What is the value of $\angle G$?

I figured out $\angle A = \angle CPB$ ,  $EF=AC$. What should I do next?
[image]

Comment: I have noticed that $\triangle AEF \cong \triangle PBC$. And if you draw $CD$, $C$ is the midpoint of a hypotenuse and $AC=CB=CD$.  Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have similar right $\triangle PCB \cong \triangle AFE$ since $PB=AE$. Hence let $CB=x=EF=AC$. Also let $PC=y=AF$.

[image]

Then $CF=AF-AC=y-x$. Complete the rectangle $PCFQ$. We get $PQ=CF=y-x$. Also $QE=QF-EF=y-x$. Hence $\triangle PQE$ is right isosceles. Using similarity or since $PQ \parallel CG$, $$\angle G = 45^{\circ}$$

Answer (score 3):

All you need is $AP = PB$ (as $AC = CB$) and so $AP = AE$.

If $\angle GAE = \theta, \angle PAE = 90^0 - 2\theta \implies  \angle APE = 45^0 + \theta$

That leads to $\angle CPG = \angle APE - \angle APC = 45^0$

So $\angle G = 45^0$

Comment: Elementary at best.

Answer (score 2):

$CP$ is orthogonal bisector of segment $AB$. Hence
$$AP = BP = AE$$ which means that triangle $AEP$ is isosceles. Therefore
$$\angle \, AEP = \angle \, APE = \alpha \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, \angle \, PAE = 180^{\circ} - 2\alpha$$
Since $\angle \, DPE = 90^{\circ} - \angle \, AEP = 90^{\circ} - \alpha$,
$$\angle \, APB = \angle \, APE - \angle \, DPE = 2\alpha - 90^{\circ}$$
But $ABP$ is isosceles ($AP = BP$), so
$$\angle \, PAG = \angle  \, PAC = 90^{\circ} - \frac{1}{2}(\angle \, APB ) = 135^{\circ} - \alpha$$
From here,
$$\angle \, EAG = \angle \, PAG - \angle \, PAE = 135^{\circ} - \alpha - 180^{\circ} + 2\alpha = \alpha - 45^{\circ}$$
Now, in triangle $AEG$ we know the angle at vertex $A$, which is $\angle \, EAG = \alpha - 45^{\circ}$ and we know the external angle at vertex $E$, which is $\angle \, AEP = \alpha$. Theretore,
$$\angle \, G = \angle \, AGE = \angle \, AEP - \angle \, EAG = \alpha - \alpha + 45^{\circ} = 45^{\circ}$$

Comment: I'm curious how you spotted the approach. I think I noticed briefly at the beginning that $\triangle APE$ was isosceles, but then dismissed it as unhelpful.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor It is a bit hard to tell, but here, in this case, the fact that the two segments $AC = BC$ were equal gave me a hint to look closer into it. Combined with the orthogonality of $PC$, one arrives at a conclusion that leads to the solution. After that it is just angle chasing that can be done in many different ways.   Plus probably experience to be able to spot things like these helps too.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We can solve this problem without point $F$. As shown above, draw segment $PA$ and altitude $AH \perp PE$ , and let $AH$ meet $PC$ at $J$ .

Because $AC=CB \;\; \& \;\; PC \perp AB$ , triangle $PAB$ is isosceles and $PA = PB$ and $\widehat{APC} = \widehat{CPB}$

Points $P , D , C , A$ are on the same circle and as you already noted $\widehat{EAG} = \widehat{CPB}$ . Therefore we have
$$\widehat{APC} = \widehat{CPB} = \widehat{EAG} = \alpha$$

Because $AE = PB$ and $PB = PA$ , triangle $APE$ is isosceles and $\widehat{PAH} = \widehat{HAE}$.
Points $P , H , D , A$ are on the same circle and $\widehat{BPG} = \widehat{HAE}$ . Therefore we have
$$\widehat{PAH} = \widehat{HAE} = \widehat{BPG} = \beta$$
Note that
$$\widehat{G} = \widehat{PJH} = 90^o - \widehat{JPH} = 90^o - (\alpha + \beta)$$
Note also that $\widehat{PJH}$ is an external angle to $\triangle PJA$ :
$$\widehat{PJH} = \widehat{JPA} + \widehat{JAP} = \alpha + \beta $$
Therefore $\widehat{G} = \widehat{PJH} = 45^o$ .

---

We can also rephrase this problem as follows:

*In isosceles triangle $PAB \;$ ($PA=PB$) we draw altitude $AD \perp PB$ and extend it to point $E$ such that $AE = PB$ . We then extend $PE$ and $AB$ to meet each other at point $G$.*

*Find $\widehat{G}$ .*